# DirectX 11 Deferred Rendering -- Wireframe data retained between frames

Tags: c++, directx-11, wireframe, deferred-rendering

I've been tasked with implementing multi-threaded support for our rendering engine and I've run into a problem I haven't been able to solve or google my way around.

When I set everything to wire-frame only it appears the rendered data is somehow being maintained from frame to frame.  For example, if I just render a box then on frame 1 I would see the mainframe in it's entirety and on frame 2 I would see nothing.  Then, if I rotate the box, I would see the wire-frame, but only the parts that aren't part of the initial wire-frame.  (It's as if the previous wire-frame is "blocking" those bits.)

This data builds up, so eventually if you rotate the box in every conceivable way nothing will render as every pixel is now occluded... somehow.

I've gone so far as to literally delete and recreate my deferred context's every single frame to see if somehow I've missed something that needs to be reset, but even this it still occurs.

If I set back to a non-deferred system, everything works perfectly.  (Basically, if everything is done on the immediate context.)

There has to be something I've missed!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you actually *clear* the screen between frames? If not; you should.

Comment: I do Jesper, but only on the immediate context.  This all does work if I do everything on the Immediate context as well, so if there is something I'm supposed to be clearing from the deferred contexts I could be making an error.

Comment: Run your app with renderdoc.org debugger, capture a frame, and you’ll be able to inspect how individual draw calls affect various render targets that you have.

Comment: Also, ensure that you specify `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` when you’re creating the device (I usually only do in debug builds), and there’re no warnings in the debug output when you’re rendering your stuff.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see where it gets me; thank you Soonts!